# Detect iOS 13 undo & redo

Tags: ios, ios13, ipados

I have a WKWebView with a custom implementation of undo and redo. I would like to be able to know when the system undo / redo are triggered (via gestures or via tapping on the keyboard assistant button in iPadOS) so that I can use my custom implementation.

Is there a public API to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways. On the iOS native side there is no public API available to take over full control AFAIK, but you can listen to UNDO notifications like this to get to know about them:

```c
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserverForName:NSUndoManagerWillUndoChangeNotification object:nil queue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
    NSLog(@"Undo Notification: %@", note);
}];
```

You will then see that the NSUndoManager responsible for that lives in `WKContentView`. To get there only swizzling helps with the known risks...

---

But there is another way that works in WebKit based browser views (as `WKWebView` is) and this is to listen to `beforeinput` events. For example for a `contenteditable` element you can add the following listener:

```js
editor.addEventListener('beforeinput', event => {
  if (event.inputType === 'historyUndo') {
    console.log('undo')
    event.preventDefault()
  }
  if (event.inputType === 'historyRedo') {
    console.log('redo')
    event.preventDefault()
  }
  console.log('some other inputType', event.inputType)
})
```

This idea was was taken from this discussion: https://discuss.prosemirror.net/t/native-undo-history/1823/3?u=holtwick

Here is a JSFiddle to test: https://jsfiddle.net/perenzo/bhztrgw3/4/

See also the corresponding TipTap plugin: https://github.com/scrumpy/tiptap/issues/468

Comment: I tried setting a UIKeyCommand with wantsPriorityOverSystemBehavior true, and then using validate, but that didn't work. Using this notification allows me to do what was missing by the system: setting setNeedsDisplay.